# Where can I find the default control templates for UWP controls?

Tags: uwp, controltemplate

I want to modify a Button control slightly (add a description).  Where can I find the default control templates for UWP controls?

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that they can be found at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic`